# Issue with @RequestParam. Data does not reach my REST

Tags: java, html, spring, forms, rest

I am trying to code an HTML form that sends data to a `RESTful` web service (managed with `Spring`) using **select** HTML element.

The `REST` has to create an object **Event** on my `database`.

The problem I find is that the `@RequestParam` in the REST comes empty even if my options' values are present.

This is my HTML form.

```
<form name="editForm" role="form" novalidate ng-submit="vm.save()">

<!-- other fields that works correct -->

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" data-translate="businessRequestApp.event.participantsAdd" for="field_attendees">Attendees</label>
            <select style="height: 300px;" multiple class="form-control" id="field_attendees" ng-model="vm.event.usersOnIt" ng-options="customUser as customUser.username for customUser in vm.customusers | orderBy:'id' track by customUser.id">
                <option value="{{customUser.username}}" name="attendeesToParse"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
</form>
```

This is my `REST`.

```
@PostMapping("/events")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<Event> createEvent(@RequestBody Event event, @RequestParam(value="attendeesToParse") List<String> participants) throws URISyntaxException {

    //Some code that creates an object "Event" on my database

}
```

I am trying to fill a field List of `String`. Due to my business logic I can't insert it into `Event`'s class, so I have to threat it separately.

Note that `@RequestBody` works correctly, the issue is only with `@RequestParam` that does not receive anything.

Thanks in advice for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Options elements are never sent. Select's value is sent. Try to move the `name="attendeesToParse"` to the select itself.

If you need multiple values create a hidden input and store selected options into the field. Use the hidden input name to get values in the controller.

Comment: Sorry for asking, how can I store selected options into an hidden input? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: See the example https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2009/07/multiple-selects-mit-spring-mvc-2/

Comment: `<select style="height: 300px;" multiple class="form-control" id="attendeesToParse" ng-model="vm.event.usersOnIt" ng-options="customUser as customUser.username for customUser in vm.customusers | orderBy:'id' track by customUser.id">
                <option value="{{customUser.username}}"></option>
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" name="attendeesToParse" value="{{getSelectedValues()}}" />` this is my new HTML. `getSelectedValues()` is a javascript function that returns an array of selected options, but again the same error...